# Opening Office Application Error: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel / Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word

Tags: excel, vb.net, ms-word, interop, office-interop

I am hoping that someone can give a little insight and/or instance.

I am experiencing an error trying to create an instance of an Excel or Word application.  The application I am working on is using interop assemblies to manipulate Excel and Word.  In both cases, I have been successful in doing so in the past, the problems/errors began only recently.   I've noticed multiple posts about similar error messages and have looked through them, but none addressed a similar issue or provided relevant insights.

In attempting to create an instance of Excel, the resulting error is similar to the following:

> {System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80080005): Retrieving
>   the COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following
>   error: 80080005 Server execution failed (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE)).    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingServices.AllocateUninitializedObject(RuntimeType
>   objectType)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Activation.ActivationServices.CreateInstance(RuntimeType
>   serverType)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Activation.ActivationServices.IsCurrentContextOK(RuntimeType
>   serverType, Object[] props, Boolean bNewObj)    at
>   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean
>   publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached,
>   RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)    at
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean
>   skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)    at
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly,
>   Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
>   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)    at
>   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)

I am encountering a similar error when trying to create an instance of Word.  Again, my code has been doing this with no problem, until recently.

I'm thinking this may have started with possibly with recent upgrades to the Office instance on my development machine.

The references for both Interop assemblies (`Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` and `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word`) associated with my project have `Embed Interop Types` set to `TRUE`)

If I am interpreting the error text correctly, the code is looking for the typelib/class id (i.e., `{00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}`) to be in the current machine's registry and cannot find it.  I did search the `\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib` folder in the registry and did not see it.  My question would be, why is it looking for that particular id?  Of course, I may be completely out in left field on this line of reasoning.

Since I am seeing similar effects in both contexts, I have to believe that the issue's cause here is on the Office level, rather than either application.  To the best of my knowledge, no change was made to the code or the Interop assembly references in the project.

Any insights and/or suggestions would, of course, be greatly appreciated.

I am using VS 2017 (64-bit) on Windows 10.

Comment: In the problem application, try using `Dim appType As Type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Excel.Application") : Dim app As Excel.Application = CType(System.Activator.CreateInstance(appType), Excel.Application)` and see it it works.  This is basically VB's CreateObject method.  If it does work, check the `appType.Guid` property;  if it is different from the CLSID in the error message, you have found the problem.

Comment: You neglect to mention the *version* or Office installed on the machine - that would be very relevant. Also, the code that triggers the error. The type libraries would be listed under a class root for the application, not under "typelib". You can try ***repairing*** the Office installation, see if that makes a difference. But if there's a bug in an update you'll probably have to either roll back the update or wait for a correction from MS, or contact MS support.

Comment: Using the code to retrieve apptype, I am getting the same CLSID: 
 {00024500-0000-0000-c000-000000000046}.   

The error is triggered when trying to instantiate a new instance of the Excel application object:

Example:   ExcelApp = New Excel.Application

I am using Excel for Office 365.

Comment: Using the code to retrieve apptype, I am getting the same CLSID: 
 {00024500-0000-0000-c000-000000000046}.   

The error is triggered when trying to instantiate a new instance of the Excel application object:

Example:   ExcelApp = New Excel.Application.

I mentioned the TypeLib folder in registry because I noticed references in that folder to the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel and Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word assemblies.
I am using Excel for Office 365.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. This problem surfaced after Office was automatically updated on my machine (as well as others at my company).  After doing some research and finding that Office interop requires that users be on the same version of Office (implying that updates would be problematic at best), I have decided to use late binding instead to get around this issue.

Comment: i have changed all my interop variable references to type Object and created my own versions of the Excel interop constants, eliminating the need for the Excel interop assembly.  So I removed that reference entirely.  The code appears to be functioning properly in the same manner as it did with the interop assembly.

Comment: @ChristopherH.Fleetwood, I just seen that you replied (if you want people to be notified, type: @UserName in your response). I'm glad you found a solution, but if by late-binding you mean that you are using VB's CreatObject function, then the `Dim app As Excel.Application = CType(System.Activator.CreateInstance(appType), Excel.Application)` should have worked as well. You don't need to go 100% with late-binding, just use an alternative method of getting the application instance and assign it to a variable defined as an interface (in the case Excel.Application).